# How to remove the gap of unavailable data in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a main dataframe of DateTime stamps as index and data as a column. I have extracted a subdatabase consisting few dates as given below.

```
subdf = 
2019-01-25 08:07:00   28.644188   
2019-02-2 08:08:00   32.747242  
2019-03-3 08:09:00   37.222275 
2019-04-6 08:10:00   38.607803  
2019-05-7 08:11:00   42.221516 
2019-05-8 08:12:00   48.756199
2019-05-9 08:13:00   54.485764
2019-05-10 08:14:00   59.634792
```

I wanted to plot the data of subdf. My code:

```
plt.plot(subdf.index,subdf['data'],'b*')
```

Output is:

[image]

I see some gaps in the plot especially when data of those dates is not available. My question is, how to remove it?

Comment: Change the dtype of the index to string instead of datetime.

Comment: @ScottBoston I am new to python. If you don't mind, could you type the code how to do it? This helps me.

Comment: Try... `df.index = df.index.astype('str')`